# On button click, display an image, wait 4 seconds and then display another image in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

on the UI side I have 2 elements:

- actionButton("flip_button", "Flip coin"),
- htmlOutput("flip_outcome")

When a button is clicked, I would like to display a flipping animation followed by the outcome of the coin flip. I can react to the button click with  ObserveEvent, however elements are only updated once at the end of observe event, so I cannot make 2 changes.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sidebarPanel(

                
            ),
            
            # Show a plot of the generated distribution
            mainPanel(
                actionButton("flip_button", "Flip coin"),
                htmlOutput("flip_outcome")
            )
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    coin_image <- reactiveVal("stationary_coin.jpg")
    
    output$flip_outcome<- renderText({
        c('<img src="',coin_image(),'">')
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$flip_button, {
        coin_image("flipping.gif")
        Sys.sleep(4)
        outcome<-sample(c("heads.jpg","tails.jpg"), 1)
        coin_image(outcome)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above for example, will only update the image once.

Comment: We can use `observe` together with `invalidateLater`. To help you with the implementation it would be better to have a minimal example.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Thank you! i've added a minimal example

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JavaScript solution. The **www** subfolder contains the files **coinTossing.gif**, **coin_head.png**, **coin_tail.png**, and **coin.js**.

##### R code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "coin.js")
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("btn", "Coin tossing", onclick = "coinTossing();"),
  br(),
  tags$div(
    id = "imgContainer",
    style = "display: none;",
    tags$img(id = "anim", src = "coinFlipping.gif", width = 400)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

##### JavaScript code (file 'coin.js'):

```js
function coinTossing(){
  $("#imgContainer").show();
  var $img = $("#anim");
  var src = $img.attr("src");
  if(src !== "coinFlipping.gif"){
    $img.attr("src", "coinFlipping.gif");
    coinTossing();
  }else{
    var u = Math.random();
    src = u < 0.5 ? "coin_head.png" : "coin_tail.png";
    setTimeout(function() {
      $img.attr("src", src);
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

Following the question in the comment.

##### R code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "coin.js")
  ),
  br(),
  actionButton("btn", "Coin tossing", onclick = "coinTossing();"),
  br(),
  tags$img(id = "anim", src = "coin_head.png", width = 400)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

##### JavaScript code (file 'coin.js'):

```js
function coinTossing(){
  var $img = $("#anim");
  var src = $img.attr("src");
  if(src !== "coinFlipping.gif"){
    $img.attr("src", "coinFlipping.gif");
    coinTossing();
  }else{
    var u = Math.random();
    src = u < 0.5 ? "coin_head.png" : "coin_tail.png";
    setTimeout(function() {
      $img.attr("src", src);
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! But how can I have a  picture of a coin be there by default before I click on the "Coin tossing" button?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shiny solution using `observe`, `invalidateLater` and a flag `vals$flag`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("btn", "Coin tossing"),
  br(),
  uiOutput("coin")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  vals <- reactiveValues(img = "coin_d.jpg",
                         flag = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    vals$flag <- TRUE
    if (vals$flag) vals$img <- "coinFlipping.gif"

  })

  observe({
    input$btn
    if (isolate(vals$flag)) {
      vals$flag <- FALSE
      invalidateLater(4000)
    } else {
      vals$img <- sample(c("coin_c.jpg","coin_d.jpg"), 1)
    }
  })

  output$coin <- renderUI({
    tags$div(
      tags$img(id = "anim", src = vals$img, width = 800)
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```